# Is deleteBy supported in Spring data 1.7.1?

Tags: spring-data

According to Spring doc at http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/

It appears it is supported in latest Spring Data (v1.7.1). However, I keep getting the following error in Eclipse:

```
Invalid derived query! No property delete found for type MyClass.
```

MyClass has a field called "Other" and I have the following:

```
public interface MyClassRepository extends CrudRepository<MyClass, Long> {

    Long deleteByOther(String other);

}
```

What I did is wrong?

Thanks for help!

Comment: Are you using STS by any chance? I think it hasn't been upgraded to consider the new prefixes already. The method should work at runtime actually. You can switch of repository method validation in the project settings or STS globally: Spring > Project Validators > Data Validator.

Comment: Oliver, thanks for your input! I am not using STS. Do you mean that I can get it work just in Eclipse via project settings? Thanks, again!!!

Answer (score 1):

if you are getting this error only in your IDE and not with build . you might needs to disable IDE Errors

for Eclipse :

window ---> preference --> Spring -->validation --> data validator --> invalid derived query .

for STS :

Spring -> Project Validators -> Data Validator -> Invalid Derived Query

here either de-activating the validation or configuring it to produce a warning instead of an error